# Decompress LZ4 stream of Unknown size

Tags: delphi, lz4

I want to decompress a LZ4 raw stream inside binary data. I read the documentation and came up with the following function. According to the code, it should keep decompressing until it runs out of compressed data, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? Also, I want to add a writeln for the compressed size.

```
function Try(inStream: TMemorySTream): Boolean;
var
  i, j, k: int64;
  orig_buff: Pansichar;
  compressed_buff: Pansichar;
  lz4StreamDecode: PLZ4_streamDecode_t;
begin
  result := false;
  lz4StreamDecode := LZ4_createStreamDecode();
  k := 0;   
  while True do
  begin
    orig_buff := allocmem(100);
    compressed_buff := allocmem(4064);
    j := inStream.Read(orig_buff^, 100);
    i := lz4.LZ4_decompress_safe_continue(lz4StreamDecode, orig_buff,
      compressed_buff, j, 4064);
    Freemem(orig_buff);
    Freemem(compressed_buff);
    if i <= 0 then
      break;
    inc(k);
  end;
  if k <> 0 then
    result := True;
  LZ4_freeStreamDecode(lz4StreamDecode);    
end;
```

**EDIT 1:** Removed the part where it freed the output buffer (temp buffer), still the problem remains, instead of decompressing entire stream and then quitting, its just exiting the loop beforehand.

```
function Try(inStream: TMemorySTream): Boolean;
var
  i, j, k: int64;
  orig_buff: Pansichar;
  compressed_buff: Pansichar;
  lz4StreamDecode: PLZ4_streamDecode_t;
begin
  result := false;
  lz4StreamDecode := LZ4_createStreamDecode();
  compressed_buff := allocmem(64 * 1024 * 1024);
  k := 0;   
  while True do
  begin
    orig_buff := allocmem(100);
    j := inStream.Read(orig_buff^, 100);
    i := lz4.LZ4_decompress_safe_continue(lz4StreamDecode, orig_buff,
      compressed_buff, j, (64 * 1024 * 1024));
    Freemem(orig_buff);
    if i <= 0 then
      break;
    inc(k);
  end;
  if k <> 0 then
    result := True;
  Freemem(compressed_buff);
  LZ4_freeStreamDecode(lz4StreamDecode);    
end;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to know the length? Isn't that the intention.

Comment: Exactly sir, you got what I'm trying to achieve :D

Comment: You are going about it the wrong way. Compress the data and store the compressed size and the data.

Comment: That would be the case if I was compressing the data, this is to decompress any LZ4  stream embedded in a dump, so am practically running this on every offset.

Comment: Why are you doing that?

Comment: To get lengths of streams inside it and offsets of them

Comment: Why did you create the file without that information? If you'd mapped out the file properly you wouldn't need to hack around like this.

Answer (score 1):

LZ4_Decompress_safe_continue uses the 'previous memory block' because the compression also relied on that. You are destroying that memory block. You must not do that. Instead you should use two buffers and switch between them. You should create the buffers before you start and only destroy them when you are finished at the end of the decompression. You say you have read the manual. I don't think you have. It gives an explicit example for doing this and also explains how it works.

### Edit

This is how I would modify your function. Sorry - unable to test

Note I am using 2 buffers and toggling between them. This is one of the things that you are missing

Also I wouldn't use Try as a function name, it is a reserved word!

```
function XTry(inStream: TMemorySTream): Boolean;
var
  i, j, k: int64;
  orig_buff: Pansichar;
  compressed_buff1, compressed_buff2: Pansichar;
  lz4StreamDecode: PLZ4_streamDecode_t;
begin
  result := false;
  lz4StreamDecode := LZ4_createStreamDecode();
  orig_buff := allocMem( 128 *1024 );
  compressed_buff1 := allocmem(1024 * 1024);
  compressed_buff2 := allocmem(1024 * 1024);
  k := 0;   
  while True do
  begin
    j := inStream.Read(orig_buff^, 128*1024);
    i := lz4.LZ4_decompress_safe_continue(lz4StreamDecode, orig_buff,
      compressed_buff1, j, 4096);  // <<<< Note 1st buffer
    if i <= 0 then
      break;
    inc(k);
    j := inStream.Read(orig_buff^, 128*1024);
    i := lz4.LZ4_decompress_safe_continue(lz4StreamDecode, orig_buff,
      compressed_buff2, j, 4096);   // Note 2nd buffer
    if i <= 0 then
      break;
    inc(k);
  end;
  if k <> 0 then
    result := True;
  LZ4_freeStreamDecode(lz4StreamDecode);    
  Freemem(compressed_buff1);
  Freemem(compressed_buff2);
  Freemem(orig_buff);

end;
```

Obviously this can be cleaned up a lot - I just wanted to keep as close to your original code as possible

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the reply. Then, it ain't compression that we need 'previous memory block' as the dictionary to find matches, although dependent blocks might need it.

So basically you are saying that I should not free compressed_buff?

Comment: Looking at the manual, it is the decompressed buffer that you specifically should not free. Instead use two such buffers and toggle between them. But personally I wouldn't free either - it just slows things down.

Comment: Edited as you said, still its the same :(

Comment: Did you compress the original? Were the original blocks only 100 bytes long? (or don't you know?) 100 bytes seems a little small...

Comment: Nah..Haven't decompressed it yet...Writing the function to decompress it

Comment: I meant are you decompressing something *you* compressed or just a random zip file?

Comment: It's actually a binary file with lz4 streams embedded inside of it